# How to read Unique Client Identifier (UCI) for Canadian Express Entry application?

Tags: immigration, canada, express-entry

I am applying on the Canadian Express Entry scheme. In the application form they asked me if I have ever applied for immigration, refugee or citizenship status of Canada before? I did apply for a visit visa last year which was refused. Should I answer yes to this question? When I answer yes, they ask me to provide the Unique Client Identifier (UCI). I found a UCI on my visa letters, but the system is not accepting that UCI because the pattern is wrong. This link (http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=013&top=4) says that the UIC either has 8 digits or 10 digits but the UIC that I found on my letter starts with an alphabetic character followed by 12 digits. What should I do? The UCI field is not mandatory so I can choose to leave it blank, but will it be misrepresentation? Please advise.

Comment: This sounds like a question for Canadian Immigration. Start with their help centre http://www.cic.gc.ca/search-recherche/index-eng.aspx?search=hc&query=UCI&s=0&l=e

Comment: they're asking whether you applied for a status which would give you long term or permanent residence. Answer no.

Answer (score 1):

1. An alphabetic character followed by 12 digits might be the "application number" and there might be another  8 digits or 10 digits above or below . Sometimes , the documents generated by CIC printer are not always aligned correctly.
2. I don't think it will be consider as misrepresentation as long as other personal details like passport number, name spelling and birthrate are accurate for CIC to identify since this UCI is just a number assigned to put your files together. Furthermore , it's common that applicants forgot or lost the UCI and CIC could find it for you on their end. I even heard applicant to be assigned another UCI accidentally and all documents will be merged into a single file later.